# George Casella book on Statistical Inference ; question 4.28

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

In question 4.28, it says let $X$ and $Y$ be independent standard normal random variables. Find the distribution of $X/|Y|$. I can understand the answer is Cauchy(0,1) distribution. Then question (c) keeps asking is the answer to part (b) surprising? Can you formulate a general theorem?

For me, it is surprising. Since from Example 4.3.6, I know $X/Y$ is also Cauchy (0,1). Thus $X/Y$ and $X/|Y|$ has the same distribution. I don't know what the authors want to emphasize here. Is there a rule?

Comment: Why are they both Cauchy? What is going on here? Are there any other such random variables X,Y such that X/Y and X/|Y| are equal in law?

Comment: If the question is as  reformulated by Andrew Zhang, an answer could be : $X/Y$ and $X/|Y|$ are both symmetrical distributions ($P(X<0)=P(X>0)$), it is not surprizing. It would be of course surprizing if it was similar for  $|X|/|Y|$ :)